# How to avoid Rufus scheduler being called as many times as there are no.of dynos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rufus-scheduler

I am running a rails app in [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) where I use [Rufus Scheduler](http://rufus.rubyforge.org/rufus-scheduler/).

My app uses more than one `dyno` and the scheduler is running on each `dyno` rather than just one, so my scheduled events are firing multiple times (once for each `dyno`).

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a new process type in your `Procfile` that runs your Rufus scheduler process:

```
web: unicorn -c app/config/unicorn.rb ... # Your existing web dyno process
scheduler: rake rufus:scheduler # Add rake task for rufus scheduler process
```

You can then use `heroku ps:scale` to set one scheduler dyno and N web dynos.

**EDIT**

You have a Rails application which currently contains your rufus scheduler.  When you deploy that application to Heroku, your Rails application code and required libraries are installed on each dyno (via one or more buildpacks).  The dyno is a virtual machine that runs a process within your application.

By default, you have a dyno that runs a Rails web app server.  If you add a second type of dyno, it will have the same codebase and libraries, but run a different process.  In this case, that second process will be your Rufus scheduler process.

Comment: where should i keep my rufus:scheduler file. I have currently used the rufus scheduler within config/initializer. so is this alright or do i have to take this from scheduler and keep in separate file?

Comment: And i need one more help. I cannot able to push my changes to heroku and it states "Too many requests for this Git repo. Please try again later." I read about this in heroku dev centre but could not find the solution.

Comment: You've got entirely too many issues.  You'll have to take this up with Heroku.